# Nginx Caching SSL Certificate?

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, amazon-ec2

Previously(successfully), I had updated my SSL certificates in the same fashion as I tried to do this time. Like 2 files I have, `domain.chained.crt` and `domain.key`.

Then ran `sudo service nginx restart`, `sudo service nginx reload` and `sudo nginx -s reload` commands, the Nginx is still serving the old certificate. On Firefox when I click *View Certificate* it is showing an old one.

[image: Old Certificate Picture]

After that, I even change the file name to `mydomain.chained1.crt` and `mydomain1.key`, then I also change the file names in nginx.conf like

```
ssl_certificate ssl/mydomain.chained1.crt;
ssl_certificate_key ssl/mydomain1.key;
```

After the changes, restarting and reloading nginx doesn't change the SSL certificate.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you need to upload your cert to CloudFront (in us-east-1) as well as update the certificate for nginx? Also, for CloudFront (not nginx sadly) you can use ACM for the cert - its free and auto-renews

Comment: Yeah, upon updating SSL of CloudFront, it's working now.